# InvalidCharacterError: String contains an invalid character, while decoding base64 to bytes using atob()

Tags: javascript, base64

I am converting a base64 String to byte array using atob() function.

I get the base64String from below code:

```
var dataURL = $("#graph-panel .canvasjs-chart-canvas").get(0).toDataURL();
```

Contents of dataURL is as follows:

```
data:image/png;base64,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…
```

The above base64 String is not a complete string I think. Whatever the string that got printed in the console I have pasted it above.

I am passing this base64 String to the following function:

```
var bytes = b64DecodeUnicode(dataUrl);

function b64DecodeUnicode(str) {
console.log(str);
// Going backwards: from bytestream, to percent-encoding, to original string.
return decodeURIComponent(atob(str).split('').map(function(c) {
    return '%' + ('00' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).slice(-2);
}).join(''));
```

}

While executing the above code I am getting the following errror:

> InvalidCharacterError: String contains an invalid character

**[EDIT]**
**Following is the complete Base64 String:**

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAu4AAAEiCAYAAACm31eYAAAgAElEQVR4nO3d+ZPc5n3n8f5f8D/AWZcrclLeILE2yuGsbG/KjuxNdg2tt7xOrPKqnLVK5dokiMobrx1XjnUgiZIMUhJ4ixSv4QGRw1O8xWvA+xje9zU8vvvD9NN8Go1G90x3D/A8eL+qUEU2Gt1PP0ADn37mwfM0BAAAAEDlNcouAAAAAIDeCO4AAACAAQjuAAAAgAEI7gAAAIABCO4AAACAAQjuAFAgSRJpNBqSJEnrsTRNW495nie+77dt4/u+eJ7X9TV935dGo9FaoigaWfmHKa8uAABzh+AOAD34vi+O47T+r4d1FWbTNBWR9lCfx/O8ttcSEXEcp7U9AADdENwBoA+qZVwFdZ0e5Ita26Mo6tg2S72+WvTW/CiKWu+lt9br2+Q9PwiC3PWq7GqdXu7sewVB0PpRon5kZMuq/1jRX1ffRmT6h4qqC7UAAHrjbAkAfVBBU4VOnd7Kng2pul5daPK6oqjQrJch+3/Vgp9t7VfrVVhX61X5fd9v+yz6uux76durz5dXFyLToV3/nOqHg+I4Ttv/87obAQA6EdwBoE+O43R0c1FUy3RRAPV9f8brgyBoheAoitrePxukRaZDsB6+s+UtKoNqne+2bV5wz75WXplEpO0HRTbwq9Z9AEAxgjsA9CEIglZw11uhlW6BVddPcM++th6g+w3uReE7CIK2MujdVbKt+b2Cu8iz1nMVvNVzsvSwnhfcu/0gAgA8Q3AHgB70LijdusP0E9x79XEfVot7UfjW3yP7I2SmLe469VqzbXEnuANAbwR3AOgh2wc7r696P8FdZDq0Zrf1PE/SNO3ax71b15d+grveip7tA68HaLVutsFdf9+8Pu76axHcAWB2CO4AUKBbK3l2/PV+g7tI54gr2RBbtG42Le76KDR6C3veCDb9Bnf177wRaUSedaHRb57V1xHcAWDmCO4AYCkCMQDYheAOAJYiuAOAXQjuAGApgjsA2IXgDgAAABiA4A4AAAAYgOAOAAAAGIDgDgAAABiA4A4AAAAYoGtw1yfP0CfK6Of52Yk49Mk/uk0Trib/AAAAANApN7ir6bdFns3ip0/BnZUkSddwHwRBK8irkN5WAO219Vn7AAAAADzTEdzTNO0I6Y7jFAbqopbybOjXw7ke6tV7500tDgAAANRdXynZ87yuLepJkrS6umTDvVqn08O653kd2/Rq3QcAAADqqK/gXjTznt5nXQV4JW/WPv0xx3E6fhDkPQYAAADUXc/gHgTBjFrAPc9rdZ0huAMAAADDURjckySZ8c2iSZK0usIMu6uMatHPLgAAAIDtuqbeNE07hnXsR5IkbTerZoeAzN6cqj93NjenEtwBAABQB7mpN03Tji4u/Y6xnt1OD+d5LfB6sM9rge+F4A4AAIA66Ei9atz27KLCdxAEbSPI6JMr5U2wlH3OsCdgIrgDAACgDmadeqsyyynBHQAAAHUw49SrWuTzWtbLQHAHAABAHRifegnuAAAAqAPjUy/BHQAAAHVgfOoluAMAAKAOjE+9BHcAAADUgfGpl+AOAACAOjA+9RLcAQAAUAfGp16COwAAAOrA+NRLcAcAAEAdGJ96Ce4AAACoA+NTL8EdAAAAdWB86iW4AwAAoA6MT70EdwAAANSB8amX4A4AAIA6MD71EtwBAABQB8anXoI7AAAA6sD41EtwBwAAQB0Yn3oJ7gAAAKgD41MvwR0AAAB1YHzqJbgDAACgDoxPvQR3AAAA1IHxqZfgDgAAgDowPvUS3AEAAFAHxqdegjsAAADqwPjUS3AHAABAHRifegnuAAAAqAPjUy/BHQAAAHVgfOoluAMAAKAOjE+9BHcAAADUgfGpl+AOAACAOjA+9RLcAQAAUAfGp16COwAAAOrA+NRLcAcAAEAdGJ96Ce4AAACoA+NTL8EdAAAAdWB86iW4AwAAoA6MT70EdwAAANSB8amX4A4AAIA6MD71EtwBAABQB11Tr+M40mg0pNFoSBRFhS+Spmnrub7vd6z3fb+1Pk3TGW3b8wMQ3AEAAFADuanX87xWwI6iSBqNhiRJ0v1FtPW+70sQBK11QRCI53ki8iyk97ttXx+A4A4AAIAa6Ei9aZp2hHTHcboGaj2Yq+31MJ0N/Xo477VtXx+A4A4AAIAa6Cv1ep7XtbuM53kdoV6F9SRJOoK1HtaLtu37AxDcAQAAUAN9pV7HcQrXZUO9eiyKoo5t9ceKtu0XwR0AAAB10DP1BkFQ2AI+l8Fd3cSqL24Yty0vLR1r2+Zprw8IAJhzLy0d6zh/s5i3/Jl2zZ168qTEIwqoh8LgniRJz5tFy+4qk3ciUSePp9p6AEA1PHrytPTAyTK85er9B/Lw8ROut8Ac6Brc0zRtu3G0myAI2oZxzLs5VR8CMntzatG2fX0A7fm//e5SccNYbj2cEhGRx084kQBA1dx+OCVuGMtvvbOk7KJgAN9atl7cMJbdk1fk+v0HXG+BOZCbktM07ejiUjTGuh7Os63oejjPa4Ev2ravD6C93vPzV4gbxnL57n0Rmf6zHScSAKiWy3fvixvG8nvRR2UXBQN4beMOccNYlhw5Iedv3+V6C8yBjuCuxm3PLip8B0EgjUajLWBXZQKmP/5wlbhhLKdv3hYRkQePHnMiAYCKOXvrjrhhLH/0wcdlFwUD+Lc9h8QNY/nFjv0yce0m11tgDsx6SJbZhOxR0IP7f1q0VtwwlqNXb4iIyD2COwBUjgp5X1u4puyiYABrTpwVN4zllbXjsvfiFa63wByYcXBXLfLZlvOy6MH9283+dvsuXhURkTtTU5xIAKBiDly6Km7YOQoYzHL4ynVxw1i+unC1bD13kestMAeMHwRdD+7/7eNE3DCWbecuiojIzQcPOZEAQMXsunBZ3DCW76zYWHZRMIB7jx6JG8by795cKGMnz3K9BeaAVcH9r9ZsETeMZeOp8yIicoPgDgCVs/nMpLhhLN9b9UnZRcGAXnh/pbhhLPP2HeF6C8wBq4L7j9ZvEzeMZfXxMyIicu0ew1MBQNWMNftG/3DdeNlFwYC+2/xL999t+ZTrLTAHrAruP/lkl7hhLEuPnhQRkSv37nMiAYCKWTlxWtwwltc27ii7KBhQ0Azs31+9mestMAesCu5vjO8RN4xlwcEJERG5dPceJxIAqJhFh4+LG8byN5/sKrsoGFB04Ji4YSzfXLKO6y0wB6wK7r/YsV/cMJa39x0REZHJOwR3AKgaFfZ+unVv2UXBgDafuSBuGMvvL1jB9RaYA1YF9//36WfihrH8y6efiYgwkxsAVNBbew+LG8byy50Hyi4KBnTm5m1xw1iem7eY6y0wB6wK7u/uPypuGMv/3bZPRJ6dUDiRAEB1/POug+KGsfxq96Gyi4Ih+Pxbi1rXWq63wGhZFdw/OJSKG8YSbNktIiKnCe4AUDk/27ZP3DCWd/cfLbsoGIKvLlxNcAfmiFXBfdnRk+KGsby+aaeIiJy4cYsTCQBUTLBlt7hhLB8eqsYM3BjMK2vHCe7AHLEquK9tjg386vptIiJy/DrBHQCq5vVNO8UNY1nWHLoXZlMDQ3C9BUbPquD+SfPu9v+xerOIiExcu8GJBAAq5tWxreKGsaxpTpYHsy05coLgDswRq4L7zvOXxA1j+c6KTSIicuTKdU4kAFAxf7lmi7hhLMnpC2UXBUOwe/IKwR2YI1YF9wOXroobxvKtZetFROQwwR0AKufllZvEDWPZfu5i2UXBEFy996AtuJe1vLR0rFWmu1OP5OnTpyXWCjAaVgX3iWs3xQ1j+drC1SIicvDyNYI7AFTMt5etFzeMZd/Fq2UXBUNy/f6DttlTy1ruTD2S2w+nuPbDWlYF97O37ogbxvKH768UkWct8Hx5AaA6/nTxWnHDWI5evVF2UWCJP4lXiRvGcuLGLUaUg9WsCu5X7t0XN4zld6PlIiKy9+IVvrwAUDFf+XA6ZJ26cbvsosAS31mxUdwwlp3nL8nOC5e49sNaVgX3u1OPxA1j+eI7S0REZM8kwR0Aqub5+SvEDWO5eOde2UWBJX60fpu4YSwrJ07JyonTXPthLauC+5OnT8UNY/mNN6e/rLsuXObLCwAV86X3lokbxnLzwcOyiwJL/Gz7s9l4391/lGs/rGVVcBcR+cLbi8UNY3n4+InsOH+RLy8AVIw6Tz949LjsosASKqz/bPu+Vojn2g8bWRfcVUvOjQcPZds5gjsAVIn6y+jnOC9jiFZOnBI3jOVH67e1us1w7YeNrAvu/2HBdN/JyTv3ZPzsJF9eAKiQe817kZ6bt7jsosAizyZg3Ni6UZVrP2xkXXD/k+ZoBSdv3JYtZwjuAFAl15qT9Xi/Xl52UWARNQTkVz5c1Rq1iGs/bGRdcP9GcwKIQ1euS3L6PF9eAKiQC7fvihvG8sKCFWUXBRZRky49984See6dJVz7YS3rgvtfLN8gbhjLnskrsongDgCVcuL6dMvoi/HqsosCyzw371lg59oPW1kX3L/7cSJuGMvWsxdl/clzfHkBoEIOXb4mbhjLN5asK7sosIyaPZXgDptZF9xfWTcubhjLhlPnZd2Js3x5AaBC1MR4f758Q9lFgWX0m1K59sNW1gX3/7Vhe3P2tNOy5vgZvrwAUCFbm6N9fffjpOyiwDL6MJBc+2Er64L7//5kl7hhLIuOnJBVKdMeA0CVbGh2YfzB2vGyiwLL6BMvce2HrawL7j/dukfcMJb5B4/JSoI7AFTKqvRMa6IcYJjU7KkEd9jMuuD+y50HxA1jeXPPIfno2Cm+vABQIUuOnBA3jOUnyc6yiwLLrJw4TXCH9awL7v+255C4YSz/tOuALD16ki8vAFTIgoMT4oaxvDG+p+yiwDI7L1wiuMN61gX395p/KvuHbXtbLTt8eQGgGubtOyJuGMvPt+8ruyiwjJo9leAOm1kX3BcePi5uGMvfbv5UFjX/zZcXAKrhXz/9TNwwln/99LOyiwLLqNlT67y8tHSsVR93pqbk6dOnJe4RjIJ1wX3FxHS/9h9v3C4xwR0AKuXnzZE/5u07UnZRYKG7U4/k7tQjeWnpWOkhuqzl1sOpth8xsIt1wX2sOenSD9eNywefpRy4AFAhb4xPj/y14OBE2UUBrPJivFrcMJbj12/J8es3yT+Wsi64bz5zQdwwlu+t/kQWfDbBgQsAFfKTZKe4YSxLjpwouyiAVV5euUncMJZt5y7KtnMXyT+Wsi64fzp5Wdwwlv/y0QaJDhzjwAWAClGzW65Kz5RdFMAqr23cIW4Yy/Jjp2QZo+pZqzC4e54nnuf19UKO40ij0ZBGo9Gxje/7rXVpmratS9O0tc73/RkWvzO4f3b5mrhhLN9csq5tMgYAQPl+sHZc3DCWDSfPlV0UwCqteWz2HpY39x4m/1iqa3DvFsLzJEkiURTlrguCoPUaKqRn3ydJEhGZDvhBEPRdeLW9TvXrenHhanmH4A4AlfLdjxNxw1i2np0suyiAVdQcCX+/Zbf8/Zbd5B9LFba4+77fV3AvainXg7l6rgrneqgXyQ/2vWSff+H2XXHDWP7g/ZXyFr84AaBS/nz5BnHDWPZMXim7KIBVxk6eEzeM5ZV14/KDtVvIP5YaOLgnSdJqnc+2lqt1Oj2se57XsU026Pf8AJnXv3b/gbhhLL/z3jL+VAQAFfONJevEDWM5dPla2UUBrHLg0rXWWO76cJiwy8DBXe+zrgK8EkWROI7T9nz9McdxOrrY5D1WJBvc7z16JG4Yy2/OWyy/2n2IAxcAKkQNWXfi+q2yiwJYZfLOPXHDWL48/yN5fv5H5B9LDaWrjM7zvFbXmWEHd/XDILvonj592jpY1Qx9HLgAUA0vLFghbhjLhdt3yy4KYJUnWv7RF9hl6ME9SZLWNmV0lRER+c15i8UN49Yd1hy4AFAN3q+XixvGcu3eg7KLAljny1pLO/nHTiMJ7vrNqtkhILM3p+rPHcbNqSIiv/PeMnHDWP7P1r0cuABQIc81G1buTT0quyiAdfS+7eQfOw09uGe7xujhPK8FXg/2eS3wveQF9xfeXyluGEvAcEgAUCmfa56Tnzx9WnZRAOu8sm6c4G65rsFdn1BJD8dBELSNIKNPrpQ3wVL2OaOegElE5MWF0zc/qam1OXABoHwPHj0WN4zlC28vLrsogJX08dvJP3aaWb8UzWxC9ijkBfdvNocb+/GG7Ry4AFARNx88FDeM5UvvLSu7KICV9GGwyT92mnFwj6Koa8t6GfKC+39dsVHcMJZX12/lwAWAirjYHK7u+fkryi4KYKXlx04R3C036xb3qsgL7t9b9Ym4YSx/xcxhAFAZp27cFjeM5Ssfriq7KICVtp27SHC3nJXB/YfNmzNUgOfABYDyHb16Q9wwlj9dvLbsogBWOn79FsHdclYG9x9vnO7b/vLKTRy4AFAR+y5eFTeM5dvL1pddFMBKtx5O5U7CZOry0tKx1me7fp+5H0QsDe5/u/lTccNY/uKjDQR3AKiI7c0/47+8clPZRQGs9cV3lsgX31mSO6a7icvUkydy9d4D8lyTlcH9H7ZNT7z0rWXr2dEAUBHJ6QvihrH85ZotZRcFsNaLC1fLi/HqsosxsH/fnEzz+v2HsnvyCnmuycrg/k+7DogbxvKN5rCQ7GgAKN+a42fEDWN5dWxr2UUBrPXyyk1W/FXrD97/WNwwlnO37siSIyfIc01WBve3muOYfn3RWnY0AFTEsqMnxQ1jeX3TzrKLAljrtU075LWNO8ouxsC+vmiNuGEsE9duyi927CfPNVkZ3OcfPCZuGMt/jFexowGgIj48lIobxhJs2V12UQBr/eOO/fKPO/aXXYyB/efl092d9168Iq+sHSfPNVkZ3BcdPi5uGMsff/AxOxoAKuLd/UfFDWP52bZ9ZRcFsNaCgxOy4OBE2cUY2H9vDuk9fnZSvrpwNXmuycrgvnJieuawFxasYEcDQEX8avchccNY/nnXwbKLAlhr4tpNmbh2s+xiDOx/jm0VN4xl7OQ5+fxbi8hzTVYG9w2nzokbxvLl+R+xowGgIn65c3rggLf2Hi67KAAq7vVNO8QNY5m3/0jb8JB1Z2Vw33p2UtwwFu/Xy9nRAFARP906PVRvdOBY2UUBUHFvjO8RN4zl7zbvJrhrrAzueyYvixvG8qXmGKDsaAAo3998skvcMJZFh4+XXRQAFaf+Qvf91ZsJ7horg/vhq9fFDWP57XeXsqMBoCJe2zj9p++VE6fLLgqAintzz6GOOXnIc5YG95M3bosbxvLcvCXsaACoiB+umx7SbezE2bKLAqDiFhycEDeM5fcXrCS4a6wM7pN37okbxvKFtxezowGgIr7XHN5t85nJsosCoOKWHTvZbIRdTHDXWBncb9x/KG4YM3wQAFTId1ZsFDeMZdeFy2UXBUDFjZ0818pw5LlnrAzuDx8/ETeM5XNvLmRHA0BFvLR0TNwwlgOXrpZdFAAVN94cIdANYyZg0lgZ3EVEfkML7exoACjf1xauETeMrZgcBsBo7b14pZXhXlk7Tp5rsja4f/GdJQR3AKiQP/rgY3HDWM7eulN2UQBU3MS1m60M94sd+8lzTdYG99+NlhPcAaBCfi+ans368t37ZRcFQMWdv323leGWHDlBnmuyNrj/4fsMHwQAVfJbzb+E3n44VXZRAFTc9fsPWhlu9+QV8lyTtcH964vWENwt9c3MZAwsLCxmLY+ePC37NAKg4tRAI24Yy9V7D0o7X83V0i9rg/u3lo3NqkJQbanW542FhcW85fNvLSr7NALAEA8fP5Hr9x+IyLNRqWxd+mVtcFfjBc+0QlBt8eHj4oax/PWG7WUXBQAAYE5ZG9y/v2Yzwd1Cf71hu7hhLPHh42UXBQAAYE5ZG9xfHdtKcLfQ8/NXiBvGkjIONAAAqBlrg/vrm3YQ3C2j+rc/P39F2UUBAACYc9YG92DLboK7ZejfDgAA6sza4P7z7fsJ7pahfzsAAKgza4P7v3z6GcHdMvRvBwAAdWZtcH973xGCu0Xo3w4AAOrO2uD+/mcpwd0i9G8HAAB1Z21wX3r0JMHdIvRvBwAAdWdtcF+dniG4W4T+7QAAoO6sDe4bT50nuFuC/u0AAAAWB/ft5y8R3C1B/3YAAIAewd3zPPE8r+eLpGkqjUZDGo2G+L7fsd73/db6NE1ntG0v3YL7votXCe6WoH87AABAQXBXYbqf4N5oNCRJEhGZDulBELTWBUHQeg0V0vvdtq8P0CW4H716g+BuCfq3AwAA9Ghx932/Z3DXg7lIZzjXg7l6TRXOe23b1wfo8vwzt+4Q3C1A/3YAAIBpAwd3z/M6WslVWE+SpCNY62G9aNu+P0CX4H757n2CuwXo3w4AADBt4ODuOI5EUZT7WBRF4jhO2zr9saJt+/4AXYL7rYdTBHcL0L8dAABgmrXBferxk7bgzmL2Qv92AABQd0Z1lVE3zGaXbh49eSIvLR0rPXSyDLb82dKxwmMQAACgDoZyc6o+jGPezan6EJDZm1OLtu3rA8zw+QAAAICJBg7uIu3hPNuKrofzvBb4om37+gAEdwAAANRA19TrOE5ud5QgCKTRaLQF7CpOwAQAAADYZNapdzYhexQI7gAAAKiDGafeKIpyW87LQnAHAABAHRifegnuAAAAqAPjUy/BHQAAAHVgfOoluAMAAKAOjE+9BHcAAADUgfGpl+AOAACAOjA+9RLcAQAAUAfGp16COwAAAOrA+NRLcAcAAEAdGJ96Ce4AAACoA+NTL8EdAAAAdWB86iW4AwAAoA6MT70EdwAAANSB8amX4A4AAIA6MD71EtwBAABQB8anXoI7AAAA6sD41EtwBwAAQB0Yn3oJ7gAAAKgD41MvwR0AAAB1YHzqJbgDAACgDoxPvQR3AAAA1IHxqZfgDgAAgDowPvUS3AEAAFAHxqdegjsAAADqwPjUS3AHAABAHRifegnuAAAAqAPjUy/BHQAAAHVgfOoluAMAAKAOjE+9BHcAAADUgfGpl+AOAACAOjA+9RLcAQAAUAfGp16COwAAAOrA+NRLcAcAAEAdGJ96Ce4AAACoA+NTL8EdAAAAdWB86iW4AwAAoA6MT70EdwAAANSB8amX4A4AAIA6MD71EtwBAABQB0NLvY7jSKPRkEajIZ7nta3zfb+1Lk3TtnVpmrbW+b4/4/cluAMAAKAOhpJ6kySRKIpy1wVB0AryKqS3FaDRkCRJRGQ64AdBMKP3JrgDAACgDoaSeotayvVgrp6rwrke6kXyg30vBHcAAADUwcCpN0mSVleXbGu5WqfTw7rneR3bZIN+LwR3AAAA1MHAqVfvs64CvBJFkTiO0/Z8/THHcTq62OQ9VoTgDgAAgDoYeur1PK/VdYbgDgAAAAzH0FNvkiStrjDD7iqjWvRZWFhYWFhYWFhYbFn6NZLgrt+s2mi0DwGZvTlVfy43p1YH9To61O3oULejQb2ODnU7OtTtaFCv5Rp67We7xujhPK8FXg/2eS3wvXAAjQb1OjrU7ehQt6NBvY4OdTs61O1oUK/lGrj29cmVsq3rec9hAiYzUK+jQ92ODnU7GtTr6FC3o0Pdjgb1Wi7ja58DaDSo19GhbkeHuh0N6nV0qNvRoW5Hg3otF7UPAAAAGIDgDgAAABjA2OAeRVGrb/xMxn2vA8dxut4voOpMDclZxPO8rsMUFc2Y22tbE+nHW/YG7Oz6Xsdjr/s6RnlPSBXpnzfvWCqqj6xe+8FxnKHsQ9PkzakhwvlgEEEQdL2/q1d9ZBXtB/198oZKnsk+NIn+fcyOTMf5YOb0z9PtuC2qj6xBrlMz2YfoZORZNDs6jeM4Xcd+r5NeXxZ9cqvsUJxZvu+3jQakf5HV++ijAekntqJtTZQd4tRxnLaL5EyPR/0CrA+PKtI+z0He8KhF25ooCILWsZM9rtT6ovrQ9doP+qhVURQNtA9Nouot+z3kfDCYbvXVqz6yivZD9gdXXtDqdx+aRAXILM4Hs5e9Vuhz7ogU10fea832OjWTfYh8RtZYdtjIXgdZ3eiz1yp5LW7dfu3mBSj94qNfiEXaL8a9tjVRtuyq5UKZyfGon7REOk9c2Va17LwHRduaKHv8OY7T9lhRfWQV7Ye8oWj1i7HN5xT12fTvP+eDwURR1DXIFdVH3usU7YfsTOJ6OJ/JPjRJ3vVL4Xwwe9njwvf91rHVqz6yBrlOzWQfIp+RV/3sjs876Oos78SXvZiIdF4UlLwLgr59djv94txrWxtkL8QzOR6LZgse9kzDpsmewHvVR1bRfsjbTq9PW88pvu9LmqYdwZ3zwWCKuhQU1UdW0X7I206vz5nsQ1Ooc6velUJ9LzkfDJf+eXrVh26Q69RM9yHyGXck5p3Mik6MdZQX3PO+TN2+mHlfJP2xvLCoHuu1rQ16de8oOh7zLqzqsbyQoz9WtK3JuvUH7lUful77IS/kqMdsPaeoY0pEOoI754PBqONCBUz9O1hUH1lF+yEv5OiPzWQfmsL3/Y6/5qjPy/lgeLLdZIrqI2uQ69RM9iG6I7hbiOA+Wnl/BiS4D051QdL7WXKhnh31mRWC++hku84R3Gev218rZhr6OB8U07vJqP8T3M1hXHAXqcefsQZBV5nRyQscdJUZnuyNjPxpfHayM1rrS7fgwvlg9vR7M+gqM3tFoY/zwfD0U490lakuI4/E7M1NNtw4Mkzdbk7N1lGvm9Gyr6n/+TLbFzl7M1q3bU3m+37XVrN+j8fsyA95N+5khz7Tb/op2tYG2c9YVB9ZRfsh7wbB7M1oNp9T8m5O5XwwPNn7B7rVR1av/ZC9QTB7c2q/+9AU3X6MqM/E+WBwURR11HGv+sga5Do1k32IfEZe9XvdHFh33e7K17+IvVq99C9TttUs+0XMtpIUbWuq7J8W1Q1/IjM/HvUTV7Z1Qj/p5bVOFG1rg+xJvVd96HrtB/1inG3lsf2ckg3uIpwPhkW/50Wkd31kFaWW1cUAAASDSURBVO0HPTDmtcDPZB+aQH3H1WfKfk85HwzO87yeDVC9WsEHuU7NZB8in7E1pvoVZm8Mqjv9T+J5F0i1Lq+fdvb5nseEKyLPRpDI63KgdDsegyDoqCNV340GEzBl6zZPt/pQx5h+Eep1XigaDcTmc0pecBfhfDAb+mft9nmLbrjO++7m7QdFnUO6hceibU2k113eMcv5YPbSNC384dytPvK+u4Ncp4q2RW/mn0UxNEEQ8CUaERtCdhXpf/nAcHE+GB3OB6PB+WB0iuYuwNwiuENEpGvLEQajWm0IQMPn+7513S6qgvPBaGS7gmB4OB+MjhpbH9VAcAcAAAAMQHAHAAAADEBwBwAAAAxAcAcAAAAMQHAHAAAADEBwBwAAAAxAcAcAAAAMQHAHAAAADEBwBwAAAAxAcAcAAAAMQHAHAAAADEBwBwAAAAxAcAcAAAAMQHAHAAAADEBwBwAAAAxAcAcAAAAMQHAHAAAADEBwBwAAAAxAcAcAAAAMQHAHAAAADEBwBwAAAAxAcAcAAAAMQHAHAAAADEBwz0iSRHzfL7sY4jhO2UUAAABAhYwkuDuOI41GQxqNRlsQDoKg9bi+eJ4nIiJpmuauV4t6Hf31s4sKvJ7ndX2Oer+sKIpa67q9RzZQd3teFEUiIuL7fuuxIAi61pleN0EQSJIk0mjwuwoAAADThp4Mfd9va7FWAbrtTZuBXkRaAVUP09nX0F9LiaIot1Vaf05e+FWPNRoNSdO09Xiaph2vl30P9cOi1/NUWFfhXX/PbtQPgGxZu/3IAAAAQL0MPbg7jtMKrEo2hOvBXa3Xg3S34K7rFtx13Vqt8wK453kd5c57D1XWXs/L/iVBtajntbpHUZT7ut3KBQAAgPoZenBXLex6MO9408x6FWqLgnv2/91Cta6ou4l6zyRJWkE+K/se6vX6KYvjOB3BvVs4932/a1mDIKDVHQAAAKPp46739da7o+jrVXDPa/3W+4Vn+7crURT17H9eFNzV9lEUdW29z75Htxb+7PbZ1nUV3NVn1VvQkyQp7NOeJAk3qgIAAGB0o8roN1tmW4x7Be65aHHvN7hnb3Ytei190bvEqOCuypj9kVJUVm5SBQAAgIgW3H+S7BQ3jGe1vDG+p+sb5PXt7tWVZtR93PVypWnaV3BXreV55epVFj24663u+uMEdwAAABQZenDP64+dDeKzDe6qW4lIcVhWZeh1c6r+vF7BXf0/29WlV1nU++k/XFSru+o+U1RWgjsAAABERhDcHcfJHUVGD7uzDe56n/mi4SCzwzDq8oZmVEE+2x+/aFQZ/fPMNLjn3eTKzakAAAAoMpJx3LN9vlXIzU7AlA2kvSZgUuG4aAImFcCLJmDqNka8Hsaz75H94dFtyRsKU1+vv5/68ZItqx7yGQ4SAAAAIiO8OdU0eRMwlY0JmAAAAKAQ3DX93PA6V7qNLQ8AAIB6IhlmJEnSc0SbuVCVHxAAAACoBoI7AAAAYACCOwAAAGAAgjsAAABgAII7AAAAYACCOwAAAGAAgjsAAABggP8PmhrfBzyexNsAAAAASUVORK5CYII=
```

Comment: The `data URI` at Question is not valid. Can you include the full `data URI` at Question?

Comment: @guest271314 I have mentioned above that, I have not got the complete base64 String.

Comment: Why do you not have the complete `data URI`?

Comment: @guest271314 I am printing the dataUrl in browser console, and I am getting only this string continued with dots in the end.

Comment: What is the full string that `console.log(dataURL)` logs?

Comment: @guest271314 The one that I have posted above is the complete string that is getting logged in `console.log(dataURL)`

Comment: That cannot be the complete string, as the result is not a valid `data URI`. Can you reproduce the code at stacksnippets? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Please don't have a conversation in the comments.
@Ankur, if you try pasting the original input, or perhaps look for a way to get your un-trimmed version of the Data, that'd be great

Comment: What is the end goal? There is probably a better way to do it.

Comment: @Kaiido My end goal is, I want to pass converted byte array to a REST Service.

Comment: So that's what I thought. You absolutely don't need to do what you are doing right now. Instead of calling `toDataURL()`, call the canvas [`toBlob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob#Polyfill) method. And then send the Blob passed in its callback to your REST service through a [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FormData), directly as mutlipart/form-data (binary).

Comment: @Kaiido Thanks it worked.....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to convert a DataURL using the `atob()` function, but you have missed a step.

The DataURL contains information about the media type and the encoding like so:

`data:[<mediatype>][;base64],<data>`

You can try retrieving only the data by using String Split on `base64,`

Try this:

`data = str.split('base64,')[1];`

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs

Comment: I have tried your solution and I am getting following error: URIError: malformed URI sequence

Comment: @Ankur That's a different question to what you asked. Looks like your mapping function call may be breaking the URI Component, try removing that first?

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved the conversion with following code:

```
var dataURL = $("#graph-panel .canvasjs-chart-canvas").get(0).toDataURL();
var byteArr = b64toArray(dataURL);

function b64toArray(b64Data){
var byteCharacters = atob(b64Data);

var byteNumbers = new Array(byteCharacters.length);
for (var i = 0; i < byteCharacters.length; i++) {
    byteNumbers[i] = byteCharacters.charCodeAt(i);
}

var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
return byteArray;}
```